# Apply zoom to multiple Amcharts 4 charts with jquery slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, amcharts4

I have a container with two or more XYCharts with dateAxis and I want to change the zoom for all my charts in the container at the same time, using a jQuery slider. I have tried to make the function below run, but it doesn't work.

```
$("#slider-range").slider({
    animate: "fast",
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 1,
    step: 0.01,
    values: [0, 1],
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        for (var i = 0; i < container.children.length; i++) {
            container.children[i].dateAxis[0].start = ui.values[0];
            container.children[i].dateAxis[0].end = ui.values[1];
        }
    }
});
```

I always get the error message 'Cannot read property 'dateAxis' of undefined'

This is my code:

```
am4core.ready(function () {
    am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);

    container = am4core.create("container", am4core.Container);
    container.width = am4core.percent(100);
    container.height = am4core.percent(100);
    container.layout = "vertical";
});

function createSimpleLineChart() {
    var chart = container.createChild(am4charts.XYChart);

    ...
    var dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
    dateAxis.baseInterval = { "timeUnit": "second", "count": 1 };
    ...
    return chart;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your slide method:

1) You're going through your container's [`children`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/container/#children_property) incorrectly. The `children` property is not an array that you can directly index; it is a [List object](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/listtemplate/) that has specific methods you can use to access each element. In this case, using the [`each`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/listtemplate/#each_method) method to loop through the children is the way to go.

2) There is no `dateAxis` property in the chart object. Each chart's axis objects are stored in the corresponding `yAxes` and `xAxes` properties, which are also List objects. Assuming each chart only has one date axis, you can access it directly by using [`getIndex`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/listtemplate/#getIndex_method). Also note that you might find calling the [`zoom`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/dateaxis/#zoom_method) method cleaner than modifying `start` and `end` directly.

Putting it all together:

```
    slide: function (event, ui) {
      container.children.each(function(chart) {
        chart.xAxes.getIndex(0).zoom({start: ui.values[0], end: ui.values[1]}, false, true);
        //chart.xAxes.getIndex(0).start = ui.values[0];
        //chart.xAxes.getIndex(0).end = ui.values[1];
      });
    }
```

Demo below:

```js
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
var container = am4core.create("container", am4core.Container);
container.width = am4core.percent(100);
container.height = am4core.percent(100);
container.layout = "vertical";

$("#slider-range").slider({
  animate: "fast",
  range: true,
  min: 0,
  max: 1,
  step: 0.01,
  values: [0, 1],
  slide: function(event, ui) {
    container.children.each(function(chart) {
      chart.xAxes
        .getIndex(0)
        .zoom({ start: ui.values[0], end: ui.values[1] }, false, true);
      //chart.xAxes.getIndex(0).start =ui.values[0];
      //chart.xAxes.getIndex(0).end =ui.values[1];
    });
  }
});

createCharts();

function createCharts() {
  var chart = container.createChild(am4charts.XYChart);
  var data = generateData();
  chart.data = data;

  var dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());

  var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

  var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
  series.dataFields.dateX = "date";
  series.dataFields.valueY = "price";
  series.tooltipText = "{valueY.value}";
  series.name = "Series 1";

  chart.zoomOutButton.disabled = true;

  chart2 = container.createChild(am4charts.XYChart);
  chart2.data = data;
  var dateAxis2 = chart2.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
  var valueAxis2 = chart2.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

  var series2 = chart2.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
  series2.columns.template.width = am4core.percent(50);
  series2.dataFields.dateX = "date";
  series2.dataFields.valueY = "quantity";
  series2.yAxis = valueAxis2;
  series2.tooltipText = "{valueY.value}";
  series2.name = "Series 2";
  chart2.zoomOutButton.disabled = true;
}

function generateData() {
  var data = [];
  var price = 100;
  var quantity = 1000;
  for (var i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
    price += Math.round((Math.random() < 0.5 ? 1 : -1) * Math.random() * 100);
    quantity += Math.round(
      (Math.random() < 0.5 ? 1 : -1) * Math.random() * 1000
    );
    data.push({ date: new Date(2000, 1, i), price: price, quantity: quantity });
  }

  return data;
}
```

```css
#container {
  width: 95%;
  height: 400px;
}
#slider-range {
  width: 95%;
  height: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"> 
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
<div id="slider-range"></div>
```